# Find the limit of $\frac{1 - x}{e^{-x}}$ where x goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I know the answer to this is negative infinity through simple analysis, however I am able to prove this using algebra. L'hopital's rule does not apply (or so I think) due to $\lim_{x->\infty}\dfrac{(1 - x)}{e^{-x}} = \dfrac{-\infty}{0}$. Is there any way to prove this using algebra. Similarly is there a way to prove the limit for the same equation to $-\infty$?

Comment: Does using epsilon-delta count as a way?

Comment: $$\left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  e^x\right) \left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  (1-x)\right)=\left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  e^x\right) \left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  -x\right)\to -\infty$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did try L'Hopital for the first case but I ended up with $\infty$ rather than $-\infty$.

Comment: @sky Riight thank you. If you post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer: Had it confused with another limit at infinity case where L'H applies even though it "shouldn't."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  e^x\right) \left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  (1-x)\right)=\left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  e^x\right) \left(\lim_{x\to \infty }  -x\right)\to -\infty$$

For $x\to -\infty$
Applying L'Hopital (don't hate me)
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1-x}{e^{-x}} = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-1}{-e^{-x}} = 0$$

Comment: In the case $x\to -\infty$, why do all that work? Just apply L'Hopital directly to get $\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1-x}{e^{-x}} = \lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{-1}{-e^{-x}} = 0$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Ah yes, silly me. Thanks.